# non-stop service for any exception

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe2

how can I make sure the service will never stop for any reason
except if it's stopped by the user.
I've tried this but  didn't succeed.

OnExecute:

```
Count := 0;
while not Terminated do
begin
  Inc(Count);
  While Count >= SecBetweenRuns do
  Begin
    Try
      Count := 0;
      ...
    Except
      on E: exception do
      Begin
        JFCLogFile1.LogText := E.Message;
        Break;
      End;
    End;
  End;
  Sleep(1000);
  ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
end;
```

If any exception occurs the service stop working and must start it again manually.
I want to break the loop and start over when exception occurs without any intervention by the user.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you showed? How does it not meet your requirement?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've been modified the question

Comment: You already know the answer - use a `try/except` block.  So what is the problem exactly? At the very least, you need to move the `ServiceThread.ProcessRequests()` call into the `try` block.

Comment: The problem is that the service always stop when an error occurs
Instead of breaking the loop and start over.

Comment: The only way that can happen is if an exception is being raised that is not being caught and is allowed to leave the `OnExecute` handler. So you are obviously not catching everything you think you are.

Comment: Personally, I suggest not using the `OnExecute` event at all. Move your logic into a separate worker thread that is started in the service `OnStart` event and terminated in the service `OnStop` event. At least that way, if the thread crashes, it won't stop the service. You can override the `TThread.DoTerminate()` method to check the `TThread.FatalException` property to detect uncaught exceptions that kill the thread.

Comment: Thank you, Can you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that can happen is if an exception is being raised that is not being caught and is allowed to leave the `OnExecute` handler. So you are obviously not catching everything you think you are.

Personally, I suggest not using the `OnExecute` event at all. Move your logic into a separate worker thread that is started in the service `OnStart` event and terminated in the service `OnStop` event. At least that way, if the thread crashes, it won't stop the service. You can override the `TThread.DoTerminate()` method to check the `TThread.FatalException` property to know if an uncaught exception killed the thread.